# PHP email subscription validation and check for existing

Tags: php, validation, email

I am creating an email subscription form in PHP and want to check for a valid address as well as if the email is already existing in my database.

My code is connecting to my database and inserting but the validation as well as checking for an existing email are not working.

No matter what I type into my form it inserts it into my database even if I don't type anything.

Here is all of my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<fieldset>

<legend>Subscribe to Our Newsletter &nbsp;</legend>

<?php if ($feedback!='')
echo('<p>'.$feedback.'</p>'); ?>

<label>Name: <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></label>

<label>Email: <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></label> 

<label><input type="submit" value="Sign Up!" /></label>

</fieldset>
</form>

<?php



$feedback='';
if (!$email) {

$feedback .= '<strong>Please enter your email address</strong><br />';

}

if (!$name) {

$feedback .= '<strong>Please enter your name</strong><br />';
}



list($username, $mailDomain) = explode("@", $email);

if (!@checkdnsrr($mailDomain, "MX")) {


$feedback .= '<strong>Invalid email domain</strong><br />';
}


if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)) {


$feedback .= '<strong>Your email address doesn\'t appear to be valid - please check and try again';

}



function cleaninput($value, $DB) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes( $value );
}
return mysql_real_escape_string( $value, $DB );

}


$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

include_once "connect.php";


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE email='$email'");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($numRows>0) {


$feedback = '<strong>That email address is already subscribed.</strong>';

}

$insertresult = mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$name', '$email')") or die (mysql_error());


    if ($insertresult) {
        $completed = true;
    }



if($competed=false) {
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method="post">
        <fieldset>
    <legend>Subscribe to OUr Newsletter &nbsp;</legend>
<?php 

if ($feedback!='')
    echo('<p>'.$feedback.'</p>'); ?>
<label>Name: <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></label>

<label>Email: <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></label>

<label><input type="submit" value="Sign Up!" /></label>

        </fieldset>
</form>

<?php

}
else {



echo('Thanks - you have subscribed to our newsletter successfully. You can unsubscribe at any time by clicking the link at the bottom of each email we send.');

}



?>
```

Also the last echo in my script is always there. It is displayed under my my form always. Not sure why that is. Maybe I have it in the wrong place in my code.

```
else {



echo('Thanks - you have subscribed to our newsletter successfully. You can unsubscribe at any time by clicking the link at the bottom of each email we send.');

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit of a mess, to be honest :) It's slightly difficult to read, but I can see at least two problems: you write `$competed` rather than `$completed` in one of your `if` statements, and you don't actually have the `INSERT` query in an `if` block: it'll always execute. Try putting it in an `else` block after the `if` block that checks whether the address is already in your database, like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE email='$email'");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($numRows>0) {
  $feedback = '<strong>That email address is already subscribed.</strong>';
}
else { 
  $insertresult = mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$name',   '$email')") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

You also don't need to use both `addslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string`; just the latter will do. And I'm not sure why you have the same form in your code twice. Surely once should do? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually copied this code from a book I just bought yesterday. Looks like I will be returning it!

Comment: If this code came from a book purporting to be a PHP/MySQL textbook, then yes, that sounds like a good idea... :) There's plenty more wrong with this code, so I wouldn't rely on any textbook that contained this as example code to learn from.